# SQL Update Query (Removing Additional Emails)

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a SQL update statement which will find and remove a specified from the email field that contains multiple email address. To put everything into context i used this query to add more emails to an existing email record.

```
UPDATE table1
SET email += `fundraiser@xyz.com,gorilla@xyz.com'
WHERE customer_id = 100
```

So the result was something like this in the email field

```
'jill@xyz.com,fundraiser@xyz.com,gorilla@xyz.com'
```

Now I want to reverse and remove the other 2 emails from the record which are `fundraiser@xyz.com` and `gorilla@xyz.com`. Could you please help create a SQL statement that would accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at replace function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Fix your data model so you have a table called `customerEmails`, with one row per customer and per email.  Don't store lists in delimited strings.

Answer (score 1):

use "STUFF(string1, start, length, add_string)" function for this purpose.
 (running the given query would delete the first email id, you may change the "start" and "length" arguments of stuff function to achieve your goal)

```
SELECT STUFF('jill@xyz.com,fundraiser@xyz.com,gorilla@xyz.com', 1, 13, '')
FROM table1
WHERE customer_id = 100
```

Comment: tested on sql 2k12

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a SubString_Index? This should get rid of the first comma and everything to the right of it.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET email=SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, ",", 1)
```